# Boost multiindex container does not compile with generic type

Tags: c++, templates, generics, visual-c++, boost-multi-index

I was trying to utilize a `boost-multiindex` container for fast and positional access. Providing something like a `std::vector` and an `std::map` at the same time. I had no problem to construct a simple `boost-multiindex` class. It worked really neat.

The problems came, as I was trying to transport my toy example to my real code. I planning to use `boost-multiindex` inside a generic tree structure, where one can set the type `T` of the values to store and the container in which to store the pointers to the nodes `Node` at the same time.

For some reasons the commented code will not run, whatever I tried. I was unable to understand the compiler error message either. :-(

I guess it should be an easy problem, but I don't know what to do.

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/sequenced_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/mem_fun.hpp>
#include <boost/timer/timer.hpp>

struct Node {
    const std::string& name() const { return mName; }

    std::string mName;
};

// @brief Knoten des allgemeinen Baums, welcher Werte vom Typ T enthält.
template<typename T, template <typename Node = GenericTreeNode<T>> typename C>
    struct GenericTreeNode {
        typedef GenericTreeNode<T, C> self_type;
        typedef T value_type;
        typedef C<self_type> cont_type;

        const std::string& name() const { return name_; }

        std::string name_;
        value_type value_;
        cont_type kids_;
    };

template<typename Node>
using BoostCont =
boost::multi_index::multi_index_container<
    Node*,
    boost::multi_index::indexed_by<
        boost::multi_index::ordered_unique<
            boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<Node, const std::string&, &Node::name> 
        >,
        boost::multi_index::sequenced<>
    >
>;

int main() {
    // Does not not compile!
    // GenericTreeNode<int, BoostCont> node;
    // node.kids_.insert(new GenericTreeNode<int, BoostCont>());

    // Compiles 
    BoostCont<Node> test;
    test.insert(new Node{ "B" });
    test.insert(new Node{ "A" });
    test.insert(new Node{ "C" });
    for (auto iter : test) {
        std::cout << iter->mName << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I'll receive the error messages:

```
error C2039: "name": Is not an element of "GenericTreeNode<int,BoostCont>"
error C2065: "name": undeclared identifier
error C2975: "PtrToMemberFunction": Invalid template argument for "boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun", constant compile time expression expected
```

Comment: `// Does not not compile!` doesn't help, what's the error?

Comment: I included the error message. Seems name is somewhat invisible?

Comment: try `boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<Node, const std::string&, typename &Node::name> `

Comment: Your code leaks memory.

Comment: Including typename &Node::name doesn't help. After a while I figured out that I have to declare the member function `name()` before the `cont_type` typedef. This resolved the compilation issue. :-)